what is the purpose the asterix after SOCKADDR in: bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &s, sizeof(s));
I haven't found an explanation to why you would put an asterix after a variable.
This is the example:
int main(){
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &Winsockdata);
    int ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in s;
    bind(ListenSocket,  (SOCKADDR*) &s, sizeof(s));

I think the brackets are used to typecast s to the sockaddr struct which was in use before sockaddr_in to ensure compatibility, but I'm not sure. But why the ampersand in s then? Wouldn't this mean that I typecast a memory address? I don't understand this.
Also, I researched that the asterix before a variable is used to convert a pointer into a value, and when I try to put the asterix before SOCKADDR like this:
bind(ListenSocket, (*SOCKADDR) &s , sizeof(s));

I get an error. This should mean that there must be a difference between putting an asterix before or after a variable. This is the error:

error: expected expression before 'SOCKADDR'


By convention, all-uppercase names are macros, not variables. You should look for what the macro SOCKADDR expands to.

It would really pay to become familiar with the basics of C language syntax and semantics, before working with more advanced concepts like network sockets.

@Barmar Microsoft is not one to stick to conventions.  :)

Microsoft frequently defines non-macro struct types that use all-uppercase names.

SOCKADDR is not a variable name but a type name.  So SOCKADDR * denotes a pointer to this type.
So in the context of the full expression:
(SOCKADDR*) &s

s is a variable of type struct sockaddr_in.  The unary & operator takes its address, giving you a pointer of type struct sockaddr_in *.  That pointer is then cast to type SOCKADDR *.

Using (SOCKADDR *) &s (aka (struct sockaddr *) &s) in this situation is the correct solution. Using &s by itself should fail to compile at all (not just issue a warning) since bind() expects a sockaddr* pointer, not a sockaddr_in* pointer.  C does not implicitly convert a pointer of one type into another pointer type, unless one of them is void*, which is not the case in this situation.

I think the brackets are used to typecast s to the sockaddr struct which was in use before sockaddr_in to ensure compatibility, but I'm not sure. But why the ampersand in s then? Wouldn't this mean that I typecast a memory address?

Yes, the code in question is indeed type-casting the address of s into a SOCKADDR* pointer.
The compiler is simply warning you (it should be erroring, though) because s is an instance of struct sockaddr_in and SOCKADDR (aka struct sockaddr) is technically an unrelated type, as far as the compiler's type system is concerned (ie, struct sockaddr_in does not derive from struct sockaddr).
Type-casting one pointer into a pointer of another unrelated type can cause problems, but in this situation the two types in question are logically related to each other as far as the socket API is concerned, so the type-cast is OK.
When the socket API was first created, there was only struct sockaddr, hence the sockaddr* parameter used in calls like bind(), connect(), getpeername(), etc.
Later struct types were introduced as new protocols were created (sockaddr_in6, sockaddr_un, sockaddr_storage, etc), and the original content of struct sockaddr was moved to struct sockaddr_in. In modern socket coding, sockaddr* is now just used as a generic pointer to any struct sockaddr_... type.
For backwards compatibility, sockaddr* parameters weren't changed in the API, but for modern coding you always need to use a specialized struct sockaddr_... type for whichever protocol you are working with, and type-cast it to sockaddr* when giving it to the API. And vice versa when you start with a sockaddr* pointer (such as when using getaddrinfo(), etc) and need to access its content.  A type-cast is required.
This is perfectly fine, as all struct sockaddr_... types are designed to be compatible with a sockaddr* pointer.  The 1st data field is the same in all struct sockaddr_... types, so any consumer of a sockaddr* pointer can know the actual type being pointed at and thus type-cast/read its memory accordingly.


Also, I researched that the asterix before a variable is used to convert a pointer into a value, and when I try to put the asterix before SOCKADDR like this:
bind(ListenSocket, (*SOCKADDR) &s , sizeof(s));
I get an error. This should mean that there must be a difference between putting an asterix before or after a variable.

When the asterisk is put in front of a pointer variable, then the pointer is dereferenced to access the thing it is pointing at. But that is not the case in this situation.  SOCKADDR is a type, not a variable.  You can put the asterisk after a type to declare a pointer to that type.  But you can't put the asterisk in front of a type, as it makes no sense to dereference a type.  That is why you are getting an error on (*SOCKADDR).

SOCKADDR is a generic type, not the original struct. All the concrete types are then cast to this. It's kind of like an abstract base class in an OO languge.

@Barmar SOCKADDR is generic now, but it wasn't always generic in the early days.

i unfortunatly don't understand how something can be related logically or even what logically related means in this context. I also don't know why you can't put the asterix behind the struct SOCKADDR (I tried to research this but maybe i just don't know where to look) im sorry.

@bangingmyheadontable You can, assuming SOCKADDR is a pseudotype. MSC defines it as  typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR; so (SOCKADDR *)&s casts the address of s to a pointer to struct sockaddr. Since bind() expects this as the type of its second parameter, I suspect SOCKADDR in your implementation may be defined differently (based on the compiler warning). You could simply pass (struct sockaddr *)&s to eliminate the warning.

@PaulLynch changing (SOCKADDR *) to (struct sockaddr *) won't change anything, its the same typecast.

@RemyLebeau True, if struct sockaddr is typedef'ed as SOCKADDR. I'm not familiar with the GCC socket support.

@PaulLynch SOCKADDR is just a Microsoft alias for struct sockaddr in the WinSock API.

@RemyLebeau Also true, but OP is using GCC. If SOCKADDR is typedef'ed the same I don't understand the compiler warning.

@PaulLynch the OP is using gcc for the compiler, but they are using the WinSock API, as evident by WSAStartup() and SOCKADDR. If you look at the code in the warning message, the (SOCKADDR*) cast is missing.  The cast is needed to avoid the warning/error.

@RemyLebeau Ah, thank you. So the cast isn't actually in the OP's code?

The compiler warning wasn't related to the code I wrote. I had a plan how to ask the question but changed it mid writing which then lead to me overlooking that I should have deleted that part. It's late for me im blind i deserve the downvote don't know what to say.
